# Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed, phpmailer via smtp gmail

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

```
 <?php
 require_once ("PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "abc@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "abcpassword";
$mail->SetFrom("abc@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("sameone@domain.com");
 if(!$mail->Send())
    {

        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Message has been sent";
    }
?>
```

I got the message:

```
2015-07-11 08:06:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO action.ticambodia.org
2015-07-11 08:06:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2015-07-11 08:06:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: c29lbmdrYW5lbEBnbWFpbC5jb20=
2015-07-11 08:06:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: a2FuZWxAbjB3 2015-07-11 08:06:17 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 mg19sm5958238oeb.10 - gsmtp
2015-07-11 08:06:17 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2015-07-11 08:06:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2015-07-11 08:06:17 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

anyone,could help to find out what is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: You'll get a lot more sympathy if you show even the slightest attempt to solve the problem yourself, especially when good advice is sitting right there in front of you. **Read your error messages**. If you follow the link to the docs provided, it tells you *exactly* what you need to do to solve your problem. You've also based your code on an old example - make sure you're using latest PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the Google side. For security reasons, Google Blocks less secure apps from accessing your Mails. But you can turn off this.

1. Sign in with "abc@gmail.com" from your browser.
2. Go to  [Allow less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
3. Click 'Turn On' Radio button.

Now check. You can able to send E-mails